# How do I check multiple dict keys for KeyError in one pass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, keyerror

I am passing one dict to multiple functions. Say : `params`

```
def func1(self,params):
    self.data=params['KEY1']
    self.value=params['KEY2']
    self.ip=params['KEY3']
    self.template=params['KEY4']
    .....
    self.log=params['KEY10']
```

To avoid KeyError, i changed above code to :

```
def func1(self,params):
    try:
        self.data=params['KEY1']
    except KeyError:
        self.data=None
    try:
        self.value=params['KEY2']
    except KeyError:
        self.value=None
      ...
      ...
```

This goes for almost 10 keys, which is defiantly not right.

Is there any way i can check all the keys in once & assign None to **only keys which are not present** in `params`.

How do i check this ? Since i am also assigning the value of a key to some variable after retrieving.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in 1 pass, but you can use the `.get` method:

```
def func1(self,params):
    self.data = params.get('KEY1')
    ...
```

`.get` returns `None` if no value is present at the requested key.